# Reporte de todo, sin id

Tags: php, pdf, sql

Anteriormente habia realizado un reporte en `pdf` donde me traia todo lo que pertenecia a un `folio`, no tuve problema en eso, ya que identificando el numero ya venia con su respectiviva informacion.

En esta ocasion quiero hacer otro `pdf`, pero este no se vincula con ningun folio o `id`, simplemente, al presionar el boton generar reporte, traera los datos. y estoy confundida en como hacer eso, que muestre todo en el `pdf` sin ser dependiente de un identificador.

Este codigo es del primer `pdf` que se hizo:

```
  if(isset($_GET['folio']))
  {
    $folio = $_GET["folio"];
    $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
    //consulta fea
    $query = 'SELECT folio, totalQty, totalPrice as precio, a.author as elaborado, authorizateBy, assignmentDate, ep.employeeNumber, ep.name as solicitante, ep.position as posicion, ei.employeeNumber,
              ei.name as cargo, ei.position, d.id, d.name,c.id , c.name as company, ad.supplies_id, ad.supplies_price, ad.supplies_name as nomarti, ad.qtySupply as cant, s.image as imageeen,
              s.brand as marca, s.model as modelo, s.id as sid, s.quantity, s.price as price
              FROM Assignments as a
              INNER JOIN Employees as ep ON ep.employeeNumber = a.employee_Petitioner
              INNER JOIN Employees as ei ON ei.employeeNumber = a.employee_InCharge
              INNER JOIN Departaments as d ON d.id = a.department_id
              INNER JOIN Companies as c ON c.id = d.company_id
              INNER JOIN AssigmentsDetail as ad ON ad.assignments_folio = a.folio
              INNER JOIN Supplies as s ON s.id = ad.supplies_id
              WHERE folio = ? AND ad.status = 1';
    $result = $connection->executeQuery($query, array($folio));
    // $arraySupplies = array();

    if ($result >0)
    {...}
```

Como se puede ver identifica el `folio` y simplemente generaba el `pdf` con los datos solicitados.

Este es el codigo del actual pdf:

```
  if(isset($_GET['x']))
    {
      $x = $_GET["x"];
      //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
      $query = 'SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt
      FROM inventory_list AS i
      INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
      INNER JOIN locatiON AS l on id_location = fkLocation
      WHERE i.quantity <= reorder_Level AND i.status = 1';

      $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($x));
      if ($result > 0) {...}
```

Mi problema es que no se como hacer que solo lo genere sin estar vinculado a un `id`, quisiera quitar el `if(isset($_GET['x']))` ya que ese no sera necesario y en mi `where` tampoco digo que en caso de ser algun `id`, me muestre los datos.

Espero me haya explicado, y me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente deja el siguiente código:

```
$connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
$query = 'SELECT i.description_item, i.quantity, u.name_unit, i.reorder_Level, i.target_Stock, l.name_location, i.commentt
FROM inventory_list AS i
INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
INNER JOIN locatiON AS l on id_location = fkLocation
WHERE i.quantity <= i.reorder_Level AND i.status = 1';

$result = $connection->executeQuery($query);

if ($result > 0) {...}
```

Habría que ver si el método "executeQuery" de la clase "MySqlServerConnection" acepta sólo un parámetro, si es así, debería funcionar sin inconvenientes.

Comment: Ya lo puse como me indicaste y me marca este error: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MySqlServerConnection::executeQuery(), 1 passed in`

Comment: Lo hice es esta manera como requiero lo que en su status sea 1, ese lo puse como identificador, y funciona perfecto, pero tengo una pregunta, Crees que pueda afectar en un futuro si lo dejo asi?

Comment: Como te indiqué, el problema es el método "executeQuery", deberías ver si existe otro método de esa clase al que le puedas enviar sólo la consulta, sin parámetros del filtrado o bien enviarle un array vacío como segundo parámetros:

    $result = $connection->executeQuery($query, []);

Comment: O bien un valor null en el segundo parámetro:

$result = $connection->executeQuery($query, null);

Answer (score 0):

Son dos cosas distintas: cuando haya un parámetro lo correcto sería usar una consulta preparada, cuando no haya parámetros, lo correcto sería usar `query` simplemente. Puedes hacerlo con el mismo método o crear un método para cada cosa.

Veamos las dos posibilidades:

### Usando el mismo método

Debido a que PHP permite usar [valores de argumentos predeterminados](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php), puedes escribir un método que acepte o no ciertos argumentos. En este caso, `executeQuery` podría recibir o no un segundo argumento `$params`. Luego dentro manejas la lógica para cuando reciba o no argumentos.

```
public function executeQuery($query,$params=NULL){
    if ( $params ) {
        /*Si se enviaron parámetros para el execute usamos esta forma*/
        $stmt=$connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        //obtener $result
    } else {
        /*Si no se enviaron parámetros usamos esta*/
        $data=$connection->query($query);
        //obtener $result
    }
    return $result;
}
```

En este caso, cuando se vaya a usar `query` sólo tienes que pasar el primer parámetro en la llamada, o sea, en vez de esto:

```
$result = $connection->executeQuery($query, array($folio));
```

Harías esto:

```
$result = $connection->executeQuery($query);
```

El método determinaría que `$params` es `NULL` y ejecutaría la consulta sin criterios.

---

### Usando métodos distintos

Se trataría de escribir un método con `prepare` y otro con `query` y llamar cada uno según convenga.

El primero ya lo tienes, el que dices que funciona. El segundo tendrías que escribirlo sin parámetros y sin `prepare`, `execute`.... solamente con `query`:

```
public function executeQueryWithOutParams($query){
        $data=$connection->query($query);
        //obtener $result
        return $result;
}
```

Cuando necesites consultas sin parámetros llamarías a este método.